# How to clean up very messy callback nesting using node-es?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using node-es, I am having problems where I want to do:

I want to index a document in 2 places. For each I want to check if a document exists. If it does, index the new document. If not, then don't. Instead, issue an update to an existing document.

My problem is my code looks similar to:

```
    es.search({
        query : {
          field : {
            animal : 'kitteh'
          }
        }
      }, function (err, data) {
           if(data.hits.length == 0) {
es.index(options, doc, function (err, data) {
  // this will result in a POST with path /bawss/man?refresh=true
});
           }
      });
```

Is there a way I could make this much cleaner so I don't have to keep nesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you'r looking for. Add more examples to your problem. If you want a cleaner code, try something like this:

```
var esSearchParams = {
    query : {
        field : {
            animal : 'kitteh'
        }
    }
}
function checkDocument(es, options, doc) { // this is a closure
    return function(err, data) {
       if(data.hits.length == 0) {
          es.index(options, doc, postResult)
       }
    }
}
function postResult(err, data) {
    // this will result in a POST with path /bawss/man?refresh=true
}
es.search(esSearchParams, checkDocument);
```